# Why the ComponentCount property of my TGroupBox returns 0?

Tags: delphi

I have a TGroupBox with several components inside, I'm trying to set the `Enabled` property of all the components which are inside of the GroupBox in this way

```
  for i := 0 to GroupBox1.ComponentCount -1 do
   if (GroupBox1.Components[i]) is TWinControl then
     TWinControl(GroupBox1.Components[i]).Enabled:=False;
```

but the ComponentCount returns always 0, what i'm missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [ComponentCount](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.ComponentCount) property is for retrieve the number of components **owned** by a component, to iterate over all the **children** controls you must use the [ControlCount](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ControlCount) and [Controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Controls) properties.

Comment: To elaborate further on this, components that are placed at design-time are **owned** by the parent `TForm` at runtime, that is why they do not appear in the `Components` list of the `TGroupBox`.  They are in the `Components` list of the `TForm` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i := 0 to GroupBox1.ControlCount - 1 do
   if (GroupBox1.Controls[i]) is TWinControl then
      TWinControl(GroupBox1.Controls[i]).Enabled:=False;
```

Comment: An explanation of the code goes a long way to make an answer useful.

Comment: On stackoverflow, Python answers often just show code. It's actually a very terse and helpful form for some questions. I don't think it's so bad an idea for Delphi either, although even a few words is better than nothing.